# Unknown column error in mysql where clouse

Tags: php, mysql

I just typed the following query in mysql, but got this error. Is there anything wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM `Vs_Health_File`.`FileTask` 
WHERE `ticket` = 0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248 LIMIT 1;
```

> **ERROR 1054 (42S22)**: Unknown column '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248' in 'where clause'

Comment: Just a tip: MySQL knows just as PHP data types. You can't put a string into a query without labeling it as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, another question, do you know how to close this question? Others are keep voting me down....@Joshua

Comment: Below the comments there should be a close link - maybe it appears just after some time. You could also try to vote for closing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single-quotation marks:

```
SELECT * FROM Vs_Health_File.FileTask WHERE ticket = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248' LIMIT 1;
```

Then the Database will interpretate it as a string.
If it's MySQL you could also use backticks for table and column-names:

```
SELECT * FROM `Vs_Health_File`.`FileTask` WHERE `ticket` = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Back ticks are not a `should`.

Comment: But what? You dont need them. - Query works without them.

Comment: That's what I am saying. That its not `required` to use those always and hence `should also use backticks` is not an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought you wanted to say, they are a "must" ;-) I'll change it to 'could'.

Answer (score 1):

You should single-quote your string literals in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `Vs_Health_File`.`FileTask` WHERE `ticket` = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes in column value like `ticket = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248'`

Answer (score 0):

Add single Quote into your Query

```
`ticket` = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248'
```

You can write Query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `Vs_Health_File`.`FileTask` WHERE `ticket` = '0ff15ff2f4b90385a75ee318e69c3248' LIMIT 1;
```

Also check if your database table contain `ticket` feald